# DB2 AS400, Hammer DB setup issue

Tags: iseries, hammerdb

I am working with Hammer DB to connect to remote DB2 AS400. However, I am running into issue in build schema.

`[IBM][CLI Driver][AS] SQL0204N  "QSYS.ANAND" is an undefined name.  SQLSTATE=42704`

user ANAND is present as I am able to connect to it using DBeaver.

In script editor I have tried to narrow down the issue by using print. The above issue is at

```
proc CreateTables { db_handle num_part count_ware tspace_dict } {
...
...
     } else {
        puts "db2 else"
        db2_exec_direct $db_handle $sql($i)
     }

}
```

Prior to this I am seeing connection established message in virtual user output.

Answer (score 0):

To troubleshoot in the script editor print the create table statements being run:

```
 } else {
        puts " running statement: $db_handle $sql($i)"
            db2_exec_direct $db_handle $sql($i)
        }
    }
}
```

And enable logging for the Virtual Users in the Virtual User dialog.
This will then print the statements being run by HammerDB and identify the problem statement. Try running this create table statement manually at a Db2 prompt with the user you are using to run HammerDB to identify what causes the issue and whether there is a difference in syntax from the Db2 LUW that HammerDB has been tested against.

```
   cat hammerdb_6376243B5EDA03E283831333.log
    Hammerdb Log @ Thu Nov 17 12:08:27 GMT 2022
    +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-
    Vuser 1:Monitor Thread
    Vuser 1:Connecting to database tpcc
    Vuser 2:Worker Thread
    Vuser 2:Waiting for Monitor Thread...
    Vuser 3:Worker Thread
    Vuser 3:Waiting for Monitor Thread...
    Vuser 4:Worker Thread
    Vuser 4:Waiting for Monitor Thread...
    Vuser 5:Worker Thread
    Vuser 5:Waiting for Monitor Thread...
    Vuser 1:Connection established
    Vuser 1:CREATING TPCC TABLES
    Vuser 1: running statement: db2sql2 CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER (C_ID INTEGER NOT NULL, C_D_ID SMALLINT NOT NULL, C_W_ID INTEGER NOT NULL, C_FIRST VARCHAR(16), C_MIDDLE CHAR(2), C_LAST VARCHAR(16), C_STREET_1 VARCHAR(20), C_STREET_2 VARCHAR(20), C_CITY VARCHAR(20), C_STATE CHAR(2), C_ZIP CHAR(9), C_PHONE CHAR(16), C_SINCE TIMESTAMP, C_CREDIT CHAR(2), C_CREDIT_LIM DECIMAL(12, 2), C_DISCOUNT REAL, C_BALANCE NUMERIC(12, 2), C_YTD_PAYMENT NUMERIC(12, 2), C_PAYMENT_CNT NUMERIC(8,0), C_DELIVERY_CNT INTEGER, C_DATA VARCHAR(500)) IN USERSPACE1 INDEX IN USERSPACE1 ORGANIZE BY KEY SEQUENCE ( C_ID STARTING FROM 1 ENDING AT 3000, C_W_ID STARTING FROM 1 ENDING at 10, C_D_ID STARTING FROM 1 ENDING AT 10 ) ALLOW OVERFLOW
    Vuser 1: running statement: db2sql2 CREATE TABLE DISTRICT (D_NEXT_O_ID INTEGER, D_TAX REAL, D_YTD DECIMAL(12, 2), D_NAME CHAR(10), D_STREET_1 CHAR(20), D_STREET_2 CHAR(20), D_CITY CHAR(20), D_STATE CHAR(2), D_ZIP CHAR(9), D_ID SMALLINT NOT NULL, D_W_ID INTEGER NOT NULL) IN USERSPACE1 INDEX IN USERSPACE1 ORGANIZE BY KEY SEQUENCE ( D_ID STARTING FROM 1 ENDING AT 10, D_W_ID STARTING FROM 1 ENDING AT 10 ) ALLOW OVERFLOW
    ...
```